# Reporting parameter of type Agent to database in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

I am using AnyLogic's database to export my output to a .csv-file. However, I am running into an issue when I want to make a column in the database table for a parameter that is of type Agent. The database does not allow that data type. I have tried setting the data type to `Other: Agent` in the database table, but it returns the following error: [image]

How have you managed this issue? Much obliged.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use type agent for a database column or for csv output... what do you expect? for anylogic to magically organize all the information of your agent nicely in the csv exactly as you expect it to be?

Instead you can for example save the id of that agent using agent.getId() if you want more info about your agent, you need to individually save each one of these info elements separately.